# How to add an object to an object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object

```
chartData = {
  datasets: []
};
```

It is meant to store datasets for Chart.js. I use this code to build the datasets from form input:

```
formData[index].value.forEach(function (value, dataset_index) {
      let data = {};
      data[formData[index].name] = value;
      chartData.datasets[dataset_index] = data;
});
```

I want chartData.datasets to have this structure:

```
datasets: [{
      label: 'apples',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
    }, {
      label: 'oranges',
      data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
    }]
```

Using the debugger I see that the line

```
"chartData.datasets[dataset_index] = data;"
```

overwrites the value at `chartData.datasets[dataset_index]` after the first loop iteration.

So I think "I need to push "data" onto the array object". Wrong. When I try

```
chartData.datasets[dataset_index].push(data);
```

I get

> TypeError: chartData.datasets[dataset_index] is undefined

Does someone know what is the proper way to add the "data" object to my `chartData.datasets` array?  I have tried all permutations of notation to no avail. I am assuming that Array methods are not available to me because `chartData.datasets[dataset_index]` is an object? Search results have proven fruitless.

**Update:**
Yes I thought about that but it doesn't work. Then you get chartData.datasets with four array elements. I want only two elements. See the data structure in the question. Also I have a snapshot of debug console after stepping thru with your suggestion. As you can see that is not the same data structure as the one I wanted.
[image: Debug console]

**Update II:**
Here is snapshot of serialized array of form input:
[image]
Hope this helps.

Update III:
here is formData[index].value snapshot
[image: formData[index].value]

Comment: It might be good to nestle in with a JavaScript tutorial for a little bit..

Comment: By all means. What JS tutorial would you suggest would help with my problem???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info contains useful curated resources. See the "Learning JavaScript" and "Interactive JavaScript learning" sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to push the data into `datasets` array:

```
chartData.datasets.push(data)
```

following my understanding of what did you describe here is a solution:

```
formData[index].value.forEach(function(value, dataset_index) {
  let data = {};
  data[formData[index].name] = value;
  chartData.datasets[dataset_index] = Object.assign(chartData.datasets[dataset_index] || {}, data);
});
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: @alan can you provide a sample data example of `formData[index].value`